# How can sto foreach a div class in smarty

Tags: foreach, smarty

This is my code and i need stop foreach the last ul and tab-content permanently i use a smarty 2

```
<div class="tabs">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    {foreach from=$languages item=v}
       <li>
          <a href="#tab_1">Example</a>
       </li>

   //  --> I Want stop this two

    <ul>
    <div class="tab-content">

   // I Want stop this two <---

       <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_1">
           <p>Example text</p>
       </div>
    </div>
   {/foreach}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the {break} Statement. Eg.

```
{$data = [1,2,3,4,5]}
  {foreach $data as $value}
    {if $value == 3}
      {* abort iterating the array *}
      {break}
    {/if}
    {$value}
  {/foreach}
  {*
    prints: 1 2
  *}
```